# boto3 version of list-objects-v2 --query command in AWS CLI

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Would like to know the python boto3 code for below AWS CLI

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 \
--bucket myBucket \
--prefix path1/path2 \
--query 'reverse(sort_by(Contents,&LastModified))[0]'
```

i didnt see any query option for list_objects_v2

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2

Answer (score 5):

The `--query` capability in the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) is a feature of the CLI itself, rather than being performed during an API call.

If you are using the boto3 [`list_object_v2()` command](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2), a full set of results is returned.

You can then **use Python to manipulate the results**.

It appears that you are wanting to list the most recent object in the bucket/path, so you could use something like:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3',region_name='ap-southeast-2')

response = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket')

print (sorted(response['Contents'], key=lambda item: item['LastModified'])[-1])
```

Comment: will this work if i have objects more than 1000?i do have for sure objects in 1000(s)

Comment: You'll have to modify the code to page through the results. One strategy could be to grab the latest from each result set and compare it to the latest of each subsequent result set (keeping only the 'latest' as each batch of 1000 is retrieved). BTW, if you only do this type of thing occasionally, [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) might be useful too.

Comment: Thanks,can you please post the code to page and grab latest and compare on each resultset,and to your other point i need to use this everyday and i dont have control on source s3 buckets to enable S3 inventory :(

Comment: No thank you. StackOverflow is a Q&A website. It is not a site where you should ask other people to write code for you. You are welcome, however, to try to code it yourself and post questions regarding any problems you experience.

Comment: sure,can you lemme know how can i enable pagination on the response here? do i need to use ContinuationToken ?

Comment: Correct. Take the `NextContinuationToken` from one call and pass it in as `ContinuationToken` on the next call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173369/discussion-between-shiv455-and-john-rotenstein).