# What is the boto3 equivalent of the following AWS CLI command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-cli

I am trying to write the following AWS CLI command in boto3:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket bucket --query "Contents[?LastModified>='2020-02-20T17:00:00'] | [?LastModified<='2020-02-20T17:10:00']"
```

My goal is to be able to list only those s3 files in a specified bucket that were created within a specific interval of time. In the example above, when I run this command it returns only files that were created between 17:00 and 17:10.

When looking at the boto3 documentation, I am not seeing anything resembling the '--query' portion of the above command, so I am not sure how to go about returning **only** the files that fall within a specified time interval.

(**Please note**: Listing all objects in the bucket and filtering from the larger list is not an option for me. For my specific use case, there are simply too many files to go this route.)

If a boto3 equivalent does not exist, is there a way to launch this exact command via a Python script?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50920360/boto3-version-of-list-objects-v2-query-command-in-aws-cli

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Just to clarify, is there no way to do this without having to retrieve all objects from the bucket first? As per my note, this is not a viable option for my use case. If boto3 does not allow for the --query part, how can I essentially run the CLI command but from Python?

Comment: You could use `subprocess.check_call`

Comment: The reason that a `--query` equivalent does not exist in boto3 is that this is a client-side filter, performed on the results of the `list-objects-v2` call. It does not happen server-side. You can implement it client-side, just as awscli does, by filtering the results.

Answer (score 0):

There's no equivalent one from boto3. But [s3pathlib](https://s3pathlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) solves your problem. **Here's the code snippet solves your problem**:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from s3pathlib import S3path

# define a bucket
p_bucket = S3Path("bucket")

# filter by last modified
for p in p_bucket.iter_objects().filter(
    # any Filterable attribute can be used for filtering
    S3Path.last_modified_at.between( 
        datetime(2000,1,1),
        datetime(2020,1,1),
    )
)：
    # do what ever you like
    print(p.console_url) # click link to open it in console, inspect results
```

If you want to use other `S3Path` attributes for filtering, and use other comparators, or even define your custom filter, you can follow this [document](https://s3pathlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/04-S3-Object-Filtering/index.html#)